# TeamCity Support For GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-8.0

According to the documents TeamCity  v8.1.x supports a GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs file now with the Assembly version patching feature however even though I have such a file in my solution and each of my projects have a link to this file the version information is not being replaced. Is there are certain location where TeamCity is looking for this file or does it just scan the entire solution tree?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771694/shared-assemblyinfo-for-uniform-versioning-across-the-solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature only got added in TeamCity 8.1.3.

In the AssemblyInfo Patcher settings there will be a "Patch GlobalAssemblyInfo:" option with a checkbox. If you check the box your (repo root)`/GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs` should be updated.

Comment: Yep that was the issue. Confirmed the same from JetBrains support team. Thanks!