# Simple approach to updating AssemblyInformationalVersion via TeamCity's AssemblyInfo patcher feature

Tags: c#, git, teamcity, teamcity-9.0, assemblyinfo

By default a Visual Studio C# Library/Console etc project comes with an `AssemblyInfo.cs` file that does not include `AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute`. TeamCity allows patching this attribute if found in `AssemblyInfo.cs` using *AssemblyInfoPatcher*.

**Problem**

A zero effort way of including `AssemblyInformationalVersion` for TeamCity.

**Possible Solutions**

- Use a `GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs` file and link to each project, *downside: each new project will have to be linked, frustratingly annoying if (**often**) forget to create link*
- Add `AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute` to all templates in `Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\`, *downside: do it on each devs machine, mainly overkill*
- A first build step that runs a script based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6771884/269452) and creates links on all `.cspproj`s, *downside: will have to check back in for patching step, overly complicated*

**Reason**

The `AssemblyInformationalVersion` is useful because you can put any text there - I like to put the git hash of the commit used to build the assembly in it

Have you a better idea?