# Assign Version Number for 10 SubProjects from common file

Tags: c#, .net, dll, .net-assembly, version-numbering

Our Application is in the windows .Net with c#

We had 10-15 SubProjects which belong to one single project and we want to assign the Version Number for each of them(each dll which belongs to the Specific Sub- Project) through the common .cs file.

So that for each Build/Release we want to touch the single File instead of the 10 AssemblyInfo.cs files

Comment: I've used this method before https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jjameson/2009/04/03/shared-assembly-info-in-visual-studio-projects/

Comment: Hi @Bradley Uffner, thanks for the answer But in my case my **Sub-Projects need to be with Different VersionNumbers**, as at the time of build all those SubProjects need to access there version numbers from the same file.. If you suggest any thing that would be helpful, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs`
You can 'Add as a link' to each project.
The Version will be defined only on the `GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs`

[here you can find more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771694/shared-assemblyinfo-for-uniform-versioning-across-the-solution)

Comment: Hi @Bruno Garcia, thanks for the answer
But in my case my **Sub-Projects need to be with Different VersionNumbers**, but at the time of build all those SubProjects need to access there version numbers from the same file..
If you suggest any thing that would be helpful, Thanks

Comment: In that case each project will require its own `AssemblyInfo.cs`. You could use a build step that reads from this 'same' file and patches each project individually. Honestly, it seems like a complicated workflow. It's easier in this case to manager Major and Minor version directly on each project (AssemblyInfo.cs) individually and let the build server add the revision/patch number.